# Which is better C Vs Python?

Tags: python, c

I am being told that Python is far superior to C in the ease of programming. I am an average( dont want to praise myself) user of C. Will it be helpful if I learn Python to implement my codes in future?

Comment: How on earth could we possibly answer? We have absolutely no idea what sort of programs you are writing. Vote to close as subjective.

Comment: Any language you learn will make you a better programmer. Of course it is easier to learn a language if you have actual use for it.

Comment: C and Python are programming languages for different purposes.  I'd strongly recommend against writing an operating system kernel in Python.

Comment: This is so much holywar question. There is no correct answer on it.

Comment: "Any language you learn will make you a better programmer" - except BASIC, if Dijkstra is to be believed.

Comment: @David I generally write programms related to image processing. I extensively use openCV library for my applications. As I am progressing, the applications are getting more and more complex and very difficult to debug.

Comment: @bubble I think you have a good question in you, it's just not this one. I recommend you write a new question but give lots of details of what your apps are doing and why you feel C is hindering you. You should ask for guidance as to whether other languages (not just Python) would be more productive and effective for you.

Comment: @David I have posted it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5381867/how-to-program-such-that-debugging-is-easy

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It depends on what do you expect from your language. For example I am developing firmware for embedded device. I can boot Linux in it and do my work in Python, but I need really fast code tuned for the hardware, so I use C on bare metal (without operating system). On the other hand, I need to develop many programs for my PC communicating with that device, mainly for developing and testing purposes. I don't need this programs to be tuned, I don't even need them to run fast. I just need them to be created quickly and to be robust and safe - so I use Python.

EDIT: When picking a language, I think you should read [Beating the Averages](http://www.paulgraham.com/avg.html)

Answer (score 4):

It's always useful to learn another language. If you're familiar with C then I'd invest some time in learning C++ and this is likely to be more immediately useful and will build on your existing skillset, but if you've got the time then learning Python is a great idea!