# How to program such that debugging is easy?

Tags: c, matlab

I am trying to develop some very complex applications based on Image processing. I use openCV extensively. However as the complexity of my programs are increasing I am finding it very difficult to debug my programs. Just for debugging I have to develop the same algorithm in Matlab alongside. The main reason for this is that even if there is any error in the matlab code the values of the variables are retained even when the code stops running or when it crashes. Since the values are there I can use different visualization tools to analyse it; like plotting it; showing it as an image.  Is there any way or feature which we can implement in C such that we can approach the same kind of behavior.

Comment: Even if not that, generic try/catch blocks with logging statements can go a LONG way.

Comment: @Matt I dont know anything about it.. can you tell me what is it. I use Visual Studio as my editor. Is there any feature which is available in it of which I am unaware ?

Comment: You can use Visual Studio's built-in debugger to step through your code - it's quite powerful.

Comment: @Matt Is there any way I can plot the data while debugging ?  In the mean time I searched for GDB. there are two files listed on the web gdb-7.2.tar.bz2 and gdb-7.2.tar.gz. I dont know which one to use. Also do you recommend to use GDB when I already have visual studio?

Comment: I'm not familiar with openCV, so you might need something like a debug build to do that. As far as I know (**full disclaimer:** I have not used VS for developing C programs), VS's debugger will suffice for C code, so there should be no need for GDB as well. If you're not familiar with a debugger, GDB will probably be difficult for you to learn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To debug vision algorithms, I highly recommend to divide your algorithm to different vision steps. Interface each step as a function to a vision environment like matlab, by building your c-program as a [plugin](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/compiler/f13-1001757.html). Then program the controller part as a matlab script instead of c. This allows you to view each vision step as an image.

Edit: You can't seem to attach the visual studio plugin using the plugin method I posted, see comment.

Comment: Sound like a great answer but I dont know 1)How to attach a piece of code written in C to matlab. 2) how to attach VS debugger to matlab. Can you tell me how to do that or can you direct me to a proper link?

Comment: sorry for my ignorance... I clicked on plugin and got it right for 1)

Comment: No problem. Btw it appears you can't attach the visual studio debugger using the method I posted. As the program is then compiled using the matlab compiler. You can however use loadlibrary and call native functions from a dll directly. The downside of this method is that you can't pass pointers.